# PHP pages dynamically?

Tags: php

I'm not asking any coding question, I'd just like to know what the 'standard' practice is. If I had PHP spit out a table or list of names/items from a database and then when you click on one of the names/items it then takes you to that page, should these pages be made dynamically or not?

For example, if it was a list of musicians, and then when you click on a musicians name it takes you to a list of their albums and then when you click on the album it has the track list, should these links/pages be done dynamically or is it best to make each musicians page normally. Basically, what I'm asking is should PHP be used to make each page or just to echo out the tables from the database.

Thank you.

Comment: Standard is to write as little duplicated content as possible. Which means a database for the musicians and albums and dynamic pages to pull the information.

Comment: Yes but where do the individual pages come from? Do i manually have to make a page for each item in the list and the information is just echoed out dynamically. (Sorry, I'm not a web developer)

Comment: You basically make a page for each view. One page queries for muscians and lists them out. Then another page accept a unique piece identifying information (typically an id) for a muscian and will query the database for all albums. And then a page that does the sam for albums to display tracks.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I wouldn't have to make a separate page for each musician and for each album?

Comment: No. If you use a database you can make a generic page for each type of data you want to show. But don't need to manually construct each page

Comment: That part I understand but for example if I am looking at a musicians page and I click on album no.5, will the information just change on the same page or should it take me to a new page? like album5.php?

Comment: Depends on how its designed. I would do musiscian.php and album.php. so when you click on a  musiscian if 3 it goes to musiscian.php?id=3 amd the musiscian page can use that data. And then when ot clicks on an album. You can go to album.php?id=5

Comment: Ahh thank you! thats exactly what I was trying to ask. Thanks for your help and patience!